# Unix find and file commands questions

Tags: file, shell, unix, command-line, find

I'm trying to give a find command that will run the file command for every regular file  within the current file system subtree. I'm trying to pass the results from:
    find . -type f
to the command 'file'.

This is the command I'm trying:
    find . -type f | file *

Should I be using > or a different argument for file?

Answer (score 0):

Find and [xargs](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) go together like umm… find and xargs:

```
find . -type f | xargs file
```

or if you want to be more careful:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 file
```

Answer (score 0):

xargs is great, and the answer by msw shows the use well.

However, you could also use the built-in exec option of find, like so:

```
 find . -type f -execdir file {} \;
```

It's not really better than xargs though.

Comment: And with modern versions of `find`, use `+` in place of `\;` to gain the benefits of `xargs` without the complexities.